# Sourcetree Can't Open Git Bash

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-bash

On Windows 8 & trying to use SourceTree as my Git client -- all works but the following:

When I hit the terminal button in Sourctree it says "It has not been possible to start the Git Bash terminal" (yes, I'm using the default SourceTree setting to launch the git bash terminal when this button is clicked).

I am able to bring up said terminal but then I have to cd into the proper directory.  Really would like the terminal button to work in SourcTree.

Comment: Yes... you guys are spot on.  I accepted latest update from Source Tree and then it stopped launching terminal correctly.  Upgraded git from 1.9.xxx and all is well.  Thank-you for the time!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, for me the solution was to upgrade GIT to newest version. I had 1.9.4 and now I have 2.6.3. It works great. Also I noticed that git has new console right now, I see more colors here :)

Comment: Yes!  it work for me , in SourceTree : Tools > options > git (table): click choose "Use embedded git" -> Click "Update embedded git"

Answer (score 9):

Check your git version. If you still have system Git 1.9.5 running, then better upgrade to 2.6.3 now. Check your Git Path too then restart SourceTree. The new git bash terminal looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful if Cygwin is installed.

Thanks for suggesting to upgrade Git, but it didn't resolve the issue for me on Windows 7.

To find out Git's location, open a new Git Bash and invoke the `which git` command:

```
$ "which git"
/usr/bin/git
```

Remove `git.exe` from `C:\cygwin\bin`.

Restarted SourceTree and it worked.